# How to do POST on a dependent Entity without a backing Repository

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I find mentions in lot of answers to Spring Data Rest design related questions to "Aggregate Root" and "Entity" together with "Value Objects".

And I think Repository equate to Aggregate Root.

**CASE 1**

My question is around this , say there are 2 Entities - User and UserSettings , represented in database as 2 tables and UserSettings having a foreign key user_id pointing to User.

In this case, i would like to do GET/POST on both User as well as UserSettings. From some posts, i found out that repositories should be at aggregate root level which would mean in this case exposing repository for only User since UserSettings depends on User completely.

Right now, i have 2 repositories with bidirectional relationships , one for each i.e UserRepository and UserSettingsRepostory , both exposed as REST services.

As a result, I do POST on UserSettings and User as

```
/app/userSettings
/app/users
```

For, GET  I use for UserSettings  & User  -

```
/app/users/{id}/userSettings
/app/users/{id}
```

If I don't expose UserSettingsRepository , what will be equivalent to POST on `/app/userSettings`, where I am currently doing as below -

```
Method - POST
Input JSON - {
"user" - "/app/users/{id}",
..
}
```

**CASE 2**

Likewise if there are following Entities/Tables - User, UserPost and UserComment - here UserComment has 2 foreign keys as UserPost as well as User.

I suppose here we have 2 aggregate roots and therefore should have 2 repositories as UserRepository and UserPostRepository.

Another way of thinking about is that since all are after all dependent on user and so we can just have 1 repository for UserRepository only.

Here too, contrary to my current state where I have even UserCommentRepository, I am not sure how to do POST on UserComment once  remove that.

Comment: I found some reference here - https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks/blob/master/src%2Ftest%2Fjava%2Forg%2Fspringsource%2Frestbucks%2Forder%2FOrderRepositoryIntegrationTest.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you you want to interact with `UserSettings` individually, they need to become dedicated resources, which means they're not part of the `User` aggregate anymore. An aggregate makes sure certain assertions are held within itself by making sure, nobody else manipulates the state of parts of it. So if you want do the latter, the aggregate is not an aggregate anymore. Spring Data REST just exposes these concepts on an HTTP level.

To keep `User` and `UserSettings` together you basically have two options:

- Introduce a dedicated state transition for the user resource by adding a link. Define the supported HTTP verbs and data structure for that resource pointed to.
- Use an HTTP `PATCH` operation on the user resource to manipulate parts of the resource.